# Can a restriction of a null-homotopic spherical map be null-homopotic?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

Let $n,q$ be positive integers. We are interested to the cases where $n>q$.

Let $F:\mathbb B^n\to\mathbb S^{q-1}$ be a continuous (differentiable, if needed) map, such that $F(1,0^{n-1})=(1,0^{q-1})$, $F(-1,0^{n-1})=(-1,0^{q-1})$ and $F(\{0\}^1\times\mathbb S^{n-2})\subset\{0\}^1\times\mathbb S^{q-2}\simeq\mathbb S^{q-2}$.

Can we find a map $G:\mathbb B^{n-1}\to \mathbb S^{q-2}$ such that $G(\theta)=F(0,\theta)\in \mathbb S^{q-2}$ for all $\theta\in\mathbb S^{n-2}$?

Comment: Perhaps add a paragraph explaining what you are looking for without formulas. I think this would make it more readable.

Comment: @ConnorMalin Sure. But I don't know how to start with. I am trying to show a null-homotopy of a total map implies a null-homotopy of a component. If $f(s,y)=(s,f''(s,y))$ is a null-homotopic map between spheres, I want to show $y\mapsto f''(0,y)$ is null-homotopic. Do you have any suggestions on what to edit?

Comment: So you are asking if a map of spheres sends a codimension 1 equator to a codimension one equator, and the original map is nullhomotopic (with no conditions on the null homotopy), does this imply the restriction of the map to the two equators is nullhomotopic?

Comment: @ConnorMalin Yes!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There exists nullhomotopic maps preserving codimension one equators such that the restriction to the equators is not nullhomotopic. Very easy examples come from taking non nullhomotopic maps of spheres and then extending them to a sphere of dimension higher by a nonsurjective map.

However, one can in fact come up with much stranger examples. I claim that for any even n, one can construct a map $S^{2n} \rightarrow S^{n+1}$ so that the restriction of the domain to every (2n-1)-sphere $x_1^2 + \dots x_{2n} ^2=t$ and codomain to the n-sphere $x_1^2 + \dots x_n ^2=t$ is nonnullhomotopic, and this map is nullhomotopic.

This fact follows immediately from the statement, "There is a nonnullhomotopic map $S^{2n-1} \rightarrow S^n$ such that the suspension of this map is trivial." This is because the suspension of the map is given by sending meridians to meridians via the map we are suspending.

Such a nullhomotopic map (for $n=2$) exists for the following reason: the Hopf map $S^3 \rightarrow S^2$ is a map that has infinite order in the homotopy groups of $S^2$. By a cute argument involving complex conjugation, the suspension of the Hopf map has order 2. Hence, twice the Hopf map is in the kernel of the suspension homomorphism, so we have proven a specific case.

For general n, this follows by computing the rational homotopy groups of $S^n$ and finding only one nontorsion group and applying the above reasoning.

Comment: Would you mind explaining the "cute argument"? Or is there any reference talk about the concrete construction? Sorry I am an analysis student and I am on the way of understanding.

Comment: @yaoliding So we define multiplication by n in $\pi_k(X)$ by precomposing with a degree n map from the sphere to itself. If $X$ is itself a sphere, we can ask whether precomposing with a degree n map and postcomposing with a degree n map are the same. By an unenlightening argument, one can conclude that at least after applying the suspension homomorphism they agree. To see they don't agree in general, we consider the Hopf map $\mathbb{C}^2 \supset S^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^1 = S^2$. We have conjugation actions on both sides $(x,y) \rightarrow (\bar{x},\bar{y})$ and

Comment: $[x,y] \rightarrow [\bar{x},\bar{y}]$. Which obviously commute with the Hopf map. This conjugation in $S^3$ is given by two reflections so is degree 1. In $S^2$ this is given by 1 reflection, so is degree -1. Since the Hopf map has infinite order, post composition by a degree -1 map is an example where the resulting map is not negative the original map. But we now deduce that its suspension has order two (or is trivial) because the above argument implies $\Sigma \eta = -\Sigma \eta$. I saw this argument in  Schwede's book on symmetric spectra. You can find the fact about suspension in there.

Comment: I also like the following argument that the suspension of the Hopf map has order 2.  We use S^3 = S(C^2) ---> P^1(C) = S^2 by sending (z1,z2) to [z1,z2]  as our model of the Hopf map.   The map from S^3 to S^3 sending (z1,z2) to (z1^k,z2^k) covers the map on P^1 sending [z1,z2] to [z1^k,z2^k].    It is easy to check that these maps have degree k^2 and k, respectively.    Therefore, $\eta \circ k^2 = k \circ \eta$.    Suspending, composition becomes commutative, so we get that (k^2-k) annihilates $\eta$ for any integer k.    Since the gcd over all k of k^2-k is 2, $\eta$ has order 2.